# React-Router "/:params" not working using Stripe API

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router, stripe-payments

So I´m currently trying to redirect from my checkout page to the "pending-payment-status" page using Stripe.

Works as follows: As soon as you hit the Pay Now- Button Stripe automatically creates the payment and afterwards redirects you to a URL, which you can define:

```
 await stripe.confirmPayment({
            elements,
            confirmParams: {
              // Make sure to change this to your payment completion page
              return_url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_WEBSITE_DOMAIN}/createAudit/`
            }
          });
```

When redirecting, Stripe puts the payment-ID and the Stripe Promise in the URL at the end, so that the URL would look something like this:

websitedomain/createAudit/?paymentID=*...*&stripepromise=*...*

It´s needed, so you can fetch the payment status on the redirected page.
Problem is, as soon as I start to use a redirect route, in case someone misstypes the url I redirect to the default page-route.
My App-Routes:

```
        <Routes>
          <Route element={<AnimationLayout />}>
            <Route path="/audit" element={<Audit />} />
            <Route
              path="/createAudit/:params"
              element={<CheckingPayment />}
            />
            <Route path="/smartx" element={<TokenSelection />} />
            <Route path="/faq" element={<FAQ />} />
            <Route path="/support" element={<Support />} />
            <Route path="/terms" element={<Terms />} />
            <Route path="/policy" element={<Policy />} />
            <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
            <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/audit" replace />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
```

As you can see, I´m using a /:params URL so I can access these parameters on the pending page, but like I said, I´m still getting redirected to the homepage again.
Any ideas?

Glad for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're confusing [query parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) and react's route parameters, which are a react-only system to improve front-end routing dynamically, it won't read stripe's query string, because it does not consider it as part of the route.
You need to look at [how to read query params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) to solve your issue.